# Mocking AVCaptureDevice with OCMock

Tags: ios, testing, avcapturesession, ocmock, avcapturedevice

I'm trying to write tests for a tap-to-focus method I've implemented for a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. I want to use a mock `AVCaptureDevice` in order to pass the various conditions and then to make sure the expected methods are called to handle the actual focusing. Below is the code I'm using.

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
{
    if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo])
    {
        if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
        {
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(focus_y, 1-focus_x);

            if ([device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus] && [device lockForConfiguration:&error])
            {
            ...
```

This is the test code I have so far:

```
id deviceMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[AVCaptureDevice class]];
[[[deviceMock stub] andReturnValue:@YES] hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[(AVCaptureDevice*)[[deviceMock stub] andReturnValue:@(AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)] position];
[[[deviceMock stub] andReturnValue:@YES] isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
[[[deviceMock stub] andReturnValue:@YES] lockForConfiguration:nil];

[[deviceMock expect] setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointZero];
[[deviceMock expect] setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
[[deviceMock expect] unlockForConfiguration];
[self waitForCompletion:0.55]; //Wait for UI animation
[deviceMock verify]
```

I'd like to perform three tests:

- [AVCaptureDevice devices] returns 0 devices and nothing happens
- [AVCaptureDevice devices] returns an incompatible device and nothing happens
- [AVCaptureDevice devices] returns a compatible device and the above test code passes

So I guess my question boils down to is there an easy way to stub and return `[AVCaptureDevice devices]` class method? Or is it safe to assume that there can only be one `AVCaptureDevice` on an `iPhone/iPad` that passes the above conditions so I could store the device as a property and rewrite the method I'm testing so that I can inject the mock `AVCaptureDevice`?

Comment: What are you confused about? Can you include pseudocode of the test you'd like to perform?

Comment: Thanks I've updated my question with some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stub the class method "devices" to return an array with the contents of your choosing.

```
id deviceMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[AVCaptureDevice class]];

// I think you need to change your return value code to this for the booleans:
[[[deviceMock stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((BOOL){YES})] hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[[[deviceMock stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((BOOL){YES})] isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
[[[deviceMock stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((BOOL){YES})] lockForConfiguration:nil];

// No need to wrap the position in an NSNumber
[(AVCaptureDevice*)[[deviceMock stub] andReturnValue:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack] position];

// Stub the class method that returns the devices array
[[[deviceMock stub] andReturn:@[ deviceMock ]] devices];

[[deviceMock expect] setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointZero];
[[deviceMock expect] setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
[[deviceMock expect] unlockForConfiguration];
[self waitForCompletion:0.55]; //Wait for UI animation
[deviceMock verify]
```

I think that should get you on your way.

Comment: Perfect I expanded the test a little and now everything is green. Thank you.